# Flutter Firebase sign-in with Apple messes up Google credentials

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin, google-authentication, apple-sign-in

I registered as an Apple developer using my gmail address. I'm writing a Flutter app that provides Google and Apple sign-in to Firebase functionality.

In Firebase the gmail identifier appears linked to both Apple and Google providers.

Somehow after signing-in with Apple whatever Google credentials were there are messed up and the displayName and photoUrl are lost. When I try to sign-in with Google again they're null.

I've seen others having a similar problem and apparently the Apple credential needs to be saved the first time the Apple sign-in has taken place in order to preserve that data, which I didn't do.

So, I have 2 questions: how can I have two separate records for Apple and Google in Firebase with the same email identifier? Secondly, how can I get the Apple credential again with the displayName and photoUrl data so I can save it in the device?

I'm using the following plug-in versions:

firebase_auth: ^0.15.4

google_sign_in: ^4.0.7

cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5

apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0

Thank you!